# ngx datatable vertical scroll with row grouping

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I am using Angular 2 ngx-datatable. When I set the vertical scroll to `true` and initialize the `groupRowsBy` parameter, the page collapses. I have lots of data so I need this virtual scroll.

This is my code:

```
   <ngx-datatable
    class='material'
    [rows]='rows'
    [columnMode]="'force'"
    [groupRowsBy]="'name'"
    [headerHeight]="50"
    [footerHeight]="50"
    [rowHeight]="50"
    [scrollbarV]="true">
    <ngx-datatable-group-header [rowHeight]="50" #myGroupHeader 
    (toggle)="onDetailToggle($event)">
      <ng-template let-group="group" let-expanded="expanded"
       ngx-datatable-group-header-template>
        <div style="padding-left:5px;">
          <a
            href="#"
            [class.datatable-icon-right]="!expanded"
            [class.datatable-icon-down]="expanded"
            title="Expand/Collapse Group"
            (click)="toggleExpandGroup(group)">
          </a>                          
        </div>
      </ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-group-header>
    <ngx-datatable-column name="Name">
    </ngx-datatable-column>
    <ngx-datatable-column name="Gender">
    </ngx-datatable-column>
  </ngx-datatable>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it is a [known bug](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/issues/960).
So as for today the only way I found to make it work is to set the `scrollbarV` to false, and then implement one myself in css:

```css
:host {
    --datatable-body-height: 100%;

    ::ng-deep {

        .datatable-body {                      
          height: var(--datatable-body-height) !important;
          overflow-y: auto;
        }
     }
}
```

Mind that angular components have encapsulation, so either set it to none in the parent component metadata or use `:host` and `::ng-deep` to get to the classes of the ngx-datatable.

I also use a variable for the body height because with the `[scrollbarV]` property set to false the body height was automatically set to auto (in my case I wanted the table to fill the whole outer div and be responsive, and with height auto it adjusted to the content of the table.) That calculation part was done in the parent component .ts file.